# Обфускация JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webpack

Есть мини игра (несколько) написанная на JS (логика на PHP) и интересует вопрос:
Есть ли смысл делать обфускацию выходного файла (использую webpack)? Если да  то какими инструментами лучше и как это скажется? (нагрузка, вес и другие факторы)

Comment: JS деобфусцируется за несколько минут разными онлайн-сервисами, которые можно найти по запросу: *"javascript деобфускация online"*. Разве что логику запутаете для понимания.

Comment: Это всё понятно, поиск никогда не подводил! Интересует ответ от знающих людей, есть ли в этом какой-нибудь "смысл-отдача"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу инструментов - можете использовать [плагин](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/webpack-obfuscator) для вебпака, но он не поддерживает source maps и вообще сыроват. Правильнее в вашей ситуации использовать [gulp](https://gulpjs.com) или [grunt](https://gruntjs.com/). Рекомендую посмотреть [скринкаст](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDyvV36pndZFLTE13V4qNWTZbeipNhCgQ) Ильи Кантора на эту тему.

По поводу целесообразности - всё зависит от размера проекта и ваших амбиций. Если игра действительно мини, то я бы не заморачивался. Разве что в образовательных целях.